# Broom Package - Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases

Tags: r, linear-regression, broom

I have a dataframe of student attributes and test scores, and I am trying to fit a linear model for each grade level (1 through 12). I am using the broom package to efficiently create a model for each grade level. Below is a simplified example dataset and the code I am using.

```
#start df creation 

grade <- rep(1:12, each = 40)
attendance_rate <- round(runif(480, min=25, max=100), 1)
test_growth <- round(runif(480, min = -12, max = 38))
binary_flag <- round(runif(480, min = 0, max = 1))
score <- round(runif(480, min = 92, max = 370))
survey_response <- round(runif(480, min = 1, max = 4))

df <- data.frame(grade, attendance_rate, test_growth, binary_flag, score, survey_response) 

df$survey_response[df$grade == 1] <- NA

# end df creation

#create train test split for each grade level
set.seed(123)

df_train <- lapply(split(seq(1:nrow(df)), df$grade), function(x) sample(x, floor(.6*length(x))))
df_test <- mapply(function(x,y) setdiff(x,y), x = split(seq(1:nrow(df)), df$grade), y = df_train)

df_train <- df[unlist(df_train),]

df_test <- df[unlist(df_test),]



#create models
models_nested <- df_train %>%
  group_by(grade) %>% nest() %>% 
  mutate(
    fit = map(data, ~ lm(score ~ attendance_rate + test_growth + binary_flag + survey_response, data = .x)),
    tidied = map(fit, tidy),
    augmented = map(fit, augment),
    glanced = map(fit, glance)
  )
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run the code block that begins with models_nested, I receive the following error:

> ```
> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
>   0 (non-NA) cases
> ```

I know this is happening because all students in 1st grade have an NA value in the survey_response column. I do not know how to resolve this without running a separate regression for 1st grade that drops the survey response column/variable entirely. Is there a way to tell the lm function to simply ignore a variable if that particular grade subset only contains null values? I obviously want to keep that variable in the regression for the other grade level models.

I did my best to make this question clear, but I will be happy to clarify in the comments if necessary.

**EDIT 6/9/2020**: I don't want to return NA for the first grade model, I would just like the linear model for first grade to run without the survey_response column. I would like the survey_response column to be included in all the other grade level models.

I hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can check for `NA` values in `survey_response` and use the model accordingly.

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df_train %>%
   group_by(grade) %>% 
   nest() %>% 
    mutate(fit = map(data, ~ if(all(is.na(.x$survey_response)))
              lm(score ~ attendance_rate + test_growth + binary_flag, data = .x) 
              else lm(score ~ attendance_rate + test_growth + binary_flag + survey_response, data = .x)),
        tidied = map(fit, tidy),
        augmented = map(fit, augment),
        glanced = map(fit, glance))


#   grade data              fit    tidied           augmented          glanced          
#   <int> <list>            <list> <list>           <list>             <list>           
# 1     1 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>   <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 11]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
# 2     2 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>   <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 11]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
# 3     3 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>   <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 11]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
# 4     4 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>   <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 11]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
# 5     5 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>   <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 11]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
# 6     6 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>   <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 11]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
# 7     7 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>   <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 11]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
# 8     8 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>   <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 11]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
# 9     9 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>   <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 11]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
#10    10 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>   <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 11]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
#11    11 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>   <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 11]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
#12    12 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>   <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 11]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I realized that I could have made my question more clear, and I apologize. I don't want to simply return NA for 1st grade, I would like an alternate linear model to run that does not include the survey response column. So I would want the following model to run for first grade only: lm(score ~ attendance_rate + test_growth + 
             binary_flag, data = .x)

Notice that the survey_response variable is removed, but again only for first grade. Is this possible? 

Thank you again for your time and input.

Comment: @rachael_learns But you don't always no that only `survey_response`. will give you an error. Sometimes `test_growth`  an also give you an error, right? How will you know that?

Comment: It is always survey_response that causes the problem - I am working with education data, and it is just a feature of this particular dataset that kids in first grade do not take this survey, while all other grades take the survey.

Comment: YES THAT WORKS!! THANK YOU SO MUCH. I hope one day I will be as good as you are at R! :D

Answer (score 0):

We can use `possibly` from `purrr`

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

poslm <- possibly(lm, otherwise = NA)
df_train %>%
   group_by(grade) %>% 
   nest() %>% 
   mutate(fit = map(data, ~ poslm(score ~ attendance_rate + test_growth + 
              binary_flag + survey_response, data = .x)), 
         tidied = map(fit, possibly(tidy, otherwise = NA)),
            augmented = map(fit, possibly(augment, otherwise = NA)),
          glanced = map(fit, possibly(glance, otherwise = NA)))
# A tibble: 12 x 6
# Groups:   grade [12]
#   grade data              fit       tidied           augmented          glanced          
#   <int> <list>            <list>    <list>           <list>             <list>           
# 1     1 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lgl [1]> <lgl [1]>        <lgl [1]>          <lgl [1]>        
# 2     2 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>      <tibble [5 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 12]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
# 3     3 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>      <tibble [5 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 12]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
# 4     4 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>      <tibble [5 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 12]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
# 5     5 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>      <tibble [5 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 12]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
# 6     6 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>      <tibble [5 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 12]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
# 7     7 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>      <tibble [5 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 12]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
# 8     8 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>      <tibble [5 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 12]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
# 9     9 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>      <tibble [5 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 12]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
#10    10 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>      <tibble [5 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 12]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
#11    11 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>      <tibble [5 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 12]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
#12    12 <tibble [24 × 5]> <lm>      <tibble [5 × 5]> <tibble [24 × 12]> <tibble [1 × 11]>
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. I realize that my question lacked some clarity. I don't want to return NA for the first grade model, I would just like the linear model for first grade to run without the survey_response column. I would like the survey_response column to be included in all the other grade level models. Is this possible?